# Controlar el flujo de requests en un socket (servidor) TCP de python

Tags: python, socket, tcp

Soy principiante en el tema de sockets con Python y, tengo el siguiente problema: estoy programando un socket TCP que recibe datos constantemente de un cliente (del cual no tengo control). Hay momentos en los que el cliente se cuelga del socket TCP a cada rato y envía información que no es útil para mí. Así que, mi idea es recibir la información de la primera vez que se cuelga del socket, y de cierta manera bloquear el socket por un tiempo determinado (ejemplo, 20 segundos); después de ese lapso de tiempo, volver a escuchar.

Creí que se podía solucionar con un time.sleep, pero en realidad esto sólo convierte más lento el proceso y va almacenando en cola los requests del cliente.

Aquí les dejo lo que he programado:

```
socket_tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket_tcp.bind((host, port)) 
socket_tcp.listen(5) 

count = 0
while True:
    conn, addr = socket_tcp.accept()
    print('successful connection')
    file = r'C:\Users\folder' + str(count) + '.json'
    count += 1
    with open(file, "wb") as f:        
        chunk = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

        while chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
            chunk = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

    conn.close()
```

Intenté controlar el flujo de requests con socket_tcp.listen(5), pero estoy entendiendo que esto es cuando son varios clientes, ¿cierto? En este caso sólo es un cliente.

¿Sería un posible camino utilizar la función select() de Python?
¿Alguna idea para solucionar esta situación?
Gracias.

Comment: guarda en un diccionario la ip del cliente y la hora en que se conecto, al momento de recibir un mensaje verifica la ip del cliente y ve si el tiempo de espera se ha cumplido

Comment: @Christian pero ¿de qué manera bloqueo el socket durante un tiempo o cómo rechazo al cliente (sabiendo su ip) durante un tiempo?

Comment: simplemente no proceses su petición. Si la diferencia entre la hora que se conectó y la hora en que envió el mensaje es menor a tu tiempo de espera no procesas el mensaje del cliente y listo.